# list of symbols with glossaries package: space between symbol and description

Tags: spacing, glossaries

I am using the `glossaries` package to make a list of symbols. Is there a simple way to manipulate the space between the symbol and the description?

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{glossaries}
\usepackage{glossary-mcols}
\newglossary[slg]{symbolslist}{syi}{syg}{List of Symbols}
\makeglossaries
\renewcommand*{\glspostdescription}{}

\newglossaryentry{symb:band_energy}{
name=\ensuremath{\epsilon_k},
description={Band energy in momentum space.},
type=symbolslist
}

\begin{document}

We will refer to the band structure as \gls{symb:band_energy}.

\printglossary[type=symbolslist, nonumberlist]

\end{document}
```

[image]
I like to increase the space between `\epsilon_k` and the description.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

One way is to define a new glossary style and use it instead of the predefined you are using (`list`).

So you can define a new style based on `list` in this way:

```
\newglossarystyle{mystyle}{%
  \glossarystyle{list}%
  \renewcommand*{\glossaryentryfield}[5]{%
    \item[\glsentryitem{##1}\glstarget{##1}{##2}]%
       \hspace{1cm}##3\glspostdescription\space ##5}%
}
```

Note `\hspace{1cm}`. Change that value to modify the spacing.

At printing time, now you have to use

```
\printglossary[style=mystyle,type=symbolslist, nonumberlist]
```

Thus, modifying your MWE to

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{glossaries}
\usepackage{glossary-mcols}
\newglossary[slg]{symbolslist}{syi}{syg}{List of Symbols}

\renewcommand*{\glspostdescription}{}

\newglossarystyle{mystyle}{%
  \glossarystyle{list}%
  \renewcommand*{\glossaryentryfield}[5]{%
    \item[\glsentryitem{##1}\glstarget{##1}{##2}]%
       \hspace{1cm}##3\glspostdescription\space ##5}%
}

\makeglossaries


\newglossaryentry{symb:band_energy}{
name=\ensuremath{\epsilon_k},
description={Band energy in momentum space.},
type=symbolslist
}

\begin{document}

We will refer to the band structure as \gls{symb:band_energy}.

\printglossary[style=mystyle,type=symbolslist, nonumberlist]

\end{document}
```

will give:

[image]

---

### Remark

If you need `\glspostdescription` to be empty only for the newly defined style, you can incorporate `\renewcommand*{\glspostdescription}{}` in the new style definition:

```
\newglossarystyle{mystyle}{%
  \glossarystyle{list}%
  \renewcommand*{\glspostdescription}{}%
  \renewcommand*{\glossaryentryfield}[5]{%
    \item[\glsentryitem{##1}\glstarget{##1}{##2}]%
       \hspace{1cm}##3\glspostdescription\space ##5}%
}
```

or even better, since we are redefining `\glossaryentryfield`, completely remove `\glspostdescription` from its definition:

```
\newglossarystyle{mystyle}{%
  \glossarystyle{list}%
  \renewcommand*{\glossaryentryfield}[5]{%
    \item[\glsentryitem{##1}\glstarget{##1}{##2}]%
       \hspace{1cm}##3\space ##5}%
}
```