# Making nice aligned glossaries

Tags: tables, glossaries, indexing

Consider the MWE below ([mystyle credit post here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/129994)  for increasing the horizontal spacing).

How can I change mystyle, so that the indentation is the same for multiple lines (red lines), and how can I change so that all entries on a page are aligned (green line)?

Is it e.g. possible to specify 5 cm width for the name/key. If it is longer it is broken (paragraph wrap like "p" in tables) in multiple rows.

So I am looking for a **'table' style for glossary.**

Thanks

[image]

**MWE**

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[savewrites,nonumberlist, seeautonumberlist]{glossaries}
\usepackage{glossary-mcols}
\newglossarystyle{mystyle}{%
  \glossarystyle{list}%
  \renewcommand*{\glossaryentryfield}[5]{%
    \item[\glsentryitem{##1}\glstarget{##1}{##2}]%
       \hspace{1cm}##3\glspostdescription\space ##5}%
}
\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{examp}{name={Short},%
    description={Just showing what I mean},%
}
\newglossaryentry{examp2}{name={A bit longer},%
    description={asd asd ad das dsd asd asd ads das dasdsa das das dsa das das dsa dsa dsa dsa d as asddas ads dsa das dsa as sda dsa dsa dsa d sa dsa dsa},%
}

\begin{document}
\printglossary[style=mystyle]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a style based upon the `long` style (which actually is a `longtable`. I used 3cm instead of 5cm; that looks enough.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage[savewrites,nonumberlist, seeautonumberlist]{glossaries}
\newglossarystyle{mystyle}{%
  \glossarystyle{long}%
  \renewenvironment{theglossary}%
     {\begin{longtable}{p{3cm}p{\glsdescwidth}}}%
     {\end{longtable}}%
}

\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{examp}{name={Short},%
    description={Just showing what I mean},%
}
\newglossaryentry{examp2}{name={A bit longer},%
    description={asd asd ad das dsd asd asd ads das dasdsa das das dsa das das dsa dsa dsa dsa d as asddas ads dsa das dsa as sda dsa dsa dsa d sa dsa dsa},%
}

\begin{document}
\glsaddall
\printglossary[style=mystyle]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: How to add this same style per chapter glossary, acronym etc. I want to add this style `super` per chapter glossary